# String request in Kotlin class

Tags: android, kotlin, request, android-volley

I m new in Kotlin and I'm trying to do a string request (with volley library and PHP)

I did this (like a Java)

```
val addUrl = "myurl"
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

val postRequest = object :  StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, addUrl,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                //Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }) {
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params.put("uid", uid.toString())
            return params
        }
    }
queue.add(postRequest)
```

and I have error at this point

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
```

Because say that I can't use "this"

> Type mismatch: inferred type is DataContainer but Context! was
>   expected

My data container don't extend `AppCompatActivity()`: so I can't use a "this@Activity" as another suggestion find online

This is the companion object

```
class DataContainer  {
    val noH = 32
    val TAG = "DataContainer"
    private var mDb : GlucoseDataBase
    private val lock = java.lang.Object()
    private var lastTimeStamp : Int = 0

    private val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    var uid:String? = null.toString()


    //private var raw_data : ByteArray = byteArrayOf()
    private var readings : MutableList<ByteArray> = mutableListOf()
    constructor(context : Context) {
        mDb = GlucoseDataBase.getInstance(context)
    }

    fun append(raw_data: ByteArray, readingTime: Long, sensorId : Long) {

        user?.let {
            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
            //val name = user.displayName
            //val email = user.email
            //val photoUrl = user.photoUrl

            // Check if user's email is verified
            //val emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified

            // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
            // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
            // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
            uid = user.uid

        }

        synchronized(lock) {
            readings.add(raw_data.copyOf())
            val timestamp = RawParser.timestamp(raw_data)
            if (timestamp == 0) {
                mDb.sensorContactDao().insert(SensorContact(0, readingTime, sensorId, 0, 0))
                return
            }
            // Timestamp is 2 mod 15 every time a new reading to history is done.
            val minutesSinceLast = (timestamp + 12) % 15
            val start = readingTime - Time.MINUTE * (15 * (noH - 1) + minutesSinceLast)
            val now_history = RawParser.history(raw_data)
            val now_recent = RawParser.recent(raw_data)

            Log.i("UID", uid.toString());



            val history_prepared = prepare(now_history, sensorId, 15 * Time.MINUTE, start, minutesSinceLast != 14 && timestamp < Time.DURATION_MINUTES, true)

            val data = history_prepared.toList();
           // val data2= data[0] //primo elemento più vecchio (di timestamp)  //proviamo con history[0]??
            //val data2 = data[0].value  // elemento valore dell più vecchio

            Log.i("Data History full p", data.toString());
            //Log.i("Data history prepared",data2.toString());

            val start_recent =
                    if (history_prepared.isEmpty()) {

                        val last = mDb.glucoseEntryDao().getLast(sensorId, true)

                        if (last != null) {
                            min(last.utcTimeStamp, readingTime - 16 * Time.MINUTE)
                        } else {
                            readingTime - 16 * Time.MINUTE
                        }
                    } else {
                        min(readingTime - 16 * Time.MINUTE, history_prepared.last().utcTimeStamp)
                    }

            val recent_prepared = prepare(now_recent, sensorId, 1 * Time.MINUTE, start_recent, true, false)
            val added = extend(recent_prepared) + extend(history_prepared)
            mDb.sensorContactDao().insert(SensorContact(0, sensorId, readingTime, timestamp, added))



            Log.i("Data recent prepared",recent_prepared.toString());

            //creating volley string request









            lastTimeStamp = timestamp
        }


        val addUrl = "myrurl"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue()

        val postRequest = object :  StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, addUrl,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                    //Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }, Response.ErrorListener {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }) {
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("uid", uid.toString())
                return params
            }
        }
        queue.add(postRequest)



    }




    fun get_sz_raw_data() : Int {
        return readings.size
    }
    fun get_raw_data(i: Int) : ByteArray{
        synchronized(lock){
            if(0<= i && i < readings.size)
                return readings[i]
            else
                return byteArrayOf()
        }
    }
    fun insert(v: List<GlucoseEntry>) {
        synchronized(lock){
            if(size() != 0) return
            for(g in v) {
                mDb.glucoseEntryDao().insert(g)
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("inserted %d vales into database", v.size))
    }

    private fun extend(v: List<GlucoseReading>) : Int {
        synchronized(lock) {
            val toExtend = v.filter { g: GlucoseReading -> g.status != 0 && g.value > 10 }
                    .map { g: GlucoseReading -> GlucoseEntry(g, 0) }
            for (r: GlucoseEntry in toExtend) {
                mDb.glucoseEntryDao().insert(r)
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Inserted into db!")
            return toExtend.size
        }
    }

    // Inspects last entry from the same sensor and filters out all that are already logged.
    private fun prepare(chunks : List<SensorChunk>,
                        sensorId : Long,
                        dt : Long,
                        start : Long,
                        certain : Boolean,
                        isHistory: Boolean) : List<GlucoseReading> {
        val lastRecent = mDb.glucoseEntryDao().getLast(sensorId, isHistory)

        if(lastRecent != null) {
            var match = -1
            for (i in 0 until chunks.size) {
                if (lastRecent.eq(chunks[i])) {
                    match = i
                }
            }
            if(match > -1) {
                val range = IntRange(match + 1, chunks.size - 1)
                if(!certain)
                    return chunks.slice(range)
                            .mapIndexed { i: Int, chunk: SensorChunk ->
                                GlucoseReading(chunk,
                                        lastRecent.utcTimeStamp + (i + 1) * dt, sensorId)
                        }
                else {
                    return chunks.mapIndexed { i: Int, chunk: SensorChunk ->
                        GlucoseReading(chunk,
                                start + i * dt, sensorId)
                    }.slice(range)
                }
            }
        }
        return chunks.mapIndexed { i: Int, chunk: SensorChunk ->
            GlucoseReading(chunk, start + i * dt, sensorId)
        }
    }
    fun nice(g : GlucoseEntry) : Boolean = g.status == 200 && (g.value < 5000 && g.value > 10)
    fun get(after: Long, before : Long) : List<GlucoseEntry> {
        return get(after, before, true)
    }
    fun get(after: Long, before : Long, nice : Boolean) : List<GlucoseEntry> {
        synchronized(lock) {
            val v = mDb.glucoseEntryDao().getBetween(after, before).orEmpty().sortedBy{ g -> g.utcTimeStamp }
            if(!nice) return v
            else return v.filter{g -> nice(g)}
        }
    }

    private fun last() : GlucoseEntry? {
        return mDb.glucoseEntryDao().getLast(false)
    }
    fun guess() : Pair<GlucoseReading, GlucoseReading>? {
        synchronized(lock){
            val last = last()
            if(last == null || !nice(last)) return null
            val last_as_reading = GlucoseReading(last.value, last.utcTimeStamp, last.sensorId, last.status, false, 0)
            val candidates = get(last.utcTimeStamp - Time.MINUTE*5, last.utcTimeStamp)
            val real = candidates.filter{g -> g.history == false && g.sensorId == last.sensorId}
            if(real.isEmpty()) return null
            val entry = real.first()
            val guess = last.value * 2 - entry.value
            val time = last.utcTimeStamp * 2 - entry.utcTimeStamp
            return Pair(last_as_reading, GlucoseReading(guess,
                    time,
                    last.sensorId, last.status, false, 0))
        }
    }
    fun lastTimeStamp() : Int {
        synchronized(lock){return lastTimeStamp}
    }

    fun size() : Int {
        synchronized(lock) {
            val sz = mDb.glucoseEntryDao().getSize()
            return sz
        }
    }

    fun insertManual(manual : ManualGlucoseEntry) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            mDb.manualEntryDao().insert(manual)
        }
    }
    companion object {


        private var INSTANCE : DataContainer? = null
        fun getInstance(context : Context) : DataContainer {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(DataContainer::class) {
                    if(INSTANCE == null)
                        INSTANCE = DataContainer(context)
                }
            }
            return this.INSTANCE!!

        }

       /* fun applicationContext() : Context {
            return INSTANCE!!.applicationContext
        }*/
        fun destroyInstance(){
            synchronized(DataContainer::class){
                GlucoseDataBase.destroyInstance()
                if(INSTANCE != null){
                    INSTANCE = null
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try using `applicationContext`

Comment: with val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext )
say me Unresolved reference: applicationContext

Comment: You already use context inside `DataContainer`. Use `context` instead of `this` then

Comment: i already tried to use al queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context) but i error on context like Unresolved reference: context

Comment: add your `DataContainer` code then

Comment: add your class or activity

Comment: @Jibin I edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `DataContainer` implementation like below and use `context`

```
class DataContainer(val context : Context)   {
    ....

    init {
        mDb = GlucoseDataBase.getInstance(context)
    }

    ....

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
}
```